# Ordenar un array posicionando los elementos true como primeros y los null como ultimos en la lista

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un array de 4 posiciones, en las cuales el usuario podra añadir datos,eliminar o editar este orden, por lo cual necesito que se ordenen los campos null en las ultimas posiciones cuando halla angun cambio al eliminar

Cada true significa que hay un numero guardado en ese campo, en este caso guardo el id de otra tabla.
Ejemplo 1

POS 0 = true 
POS 2 = NULL
POS 3 = true
POS 4 = true

Resultado ejempplo 1

POS 0 = true
POS 2 = true
POS 3 = true
POS 4 = Null

```
foreach ($lista_espera as $key => $data) {

echo "POSICION $key:  "; echo "ESTADO : "   ;
if ($data->posicion==true ) {
echo "Existen un dato";
}

else {

echo "Es Null";

}

echo"\n";

}
```

*Con el codigo que les muestro solon detecto cual posicion esta true o null*

Comment: ¿qué has intentado? ¿es un array en PHP, en JavaScript o en qué?

Comment: php o javascript me sirve, pero digamos que en este caso usemos php, he intentado con for y foreach haciendo comparanciones con la posicion anterior pero sin resultados

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código (como texto, no como imagen) que has intentado.

Comment: podrias publicar la forma de tu arreglo es clave valor?

Comment: @Shaz no hay imagenes en mi pregunta, solo texto

Comment: De nuevo: por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado...

Answer (score 0):

Muy fácil, con la función nativa de php *arsort*. Ejemplo:

```
$fruits = array("d" => true, "a" => null, "b" => true, "c" => true);
arsort($fruits);
```

Resultado:

```
array (size=4)
  'b' => boolean true
  'd' => boolean true
  'c' => boolean true
  'a' => null
```

Un saludo